# Do shedim receive schar?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come, soul, middos-character-traits

Given that shedim can either do good or bad and are intelligent, speaking creations in this world, can they be punished and rewarded? Do they have mitzvos? Will they exist in olam haba?

Comment: A shady question

Comment: I was under the impression that they always do bad. Although some seem to do good and I suppose they always do good. Not that they have a choice.

Comment: I think the question should be phrased as "the status of Shedim in Judaism" which will cover all your questions.